# Add jQuery click handler to multiple elements?

Tags: jquery

I need to have a `for` loop inside my jQuery.

Example:

```
  for(i=0;i<counter;i++)
   {
    $("div"+i+"").click(function(){//some code});
   }
```

How can I accomplish this?

---

#### EDIT:

This code was posted by the OP in a comment to one of the answers:

```
$("#displayPanel div").click(function (){ alert($(this).attr("id")); } 

<div id="displayPanel" class="displayPanel"> 
  <div id="heading"> Display Panel </div> <br/> 
  <div id="save" class="saveClass"></div> <br/> 
  <div id="field1" class="my"> 
    <label id="labelstr1">Untitled1</label> 
    <input id="inputstr1" type="text"/> 
  </div> 
  <div id="field2" class="my"> 
    <label id="labelstr2">Untitled1</label> 
    <input id="inputstr2" type="text"/> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

The alert is showing me the id for the first two `div`s and not for the `field1` and `field2`.

---

#### Note:

The `Field1` and `Field2` `div`s are created on the fly.

Comment: I have some 5 divs created...At the end if i click any one of the Div say Div1,i need to do some funtionality..Suggest me....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put the divs with a common class

```
<div id="d1" class="your_css_class your_control_class">
<div id="d2" class="your_css_class your_control_class">
<div id="d3" class="your_css_class your_control_class">
<div id="d4" class="your_css_class your_control_class">
<div id="d5" class="your_css_class your_control_class">

$(".your_control_class").click(function(){
   var div_id=$(this).attr("id"); // gives you the ID of the clicked div
   if(div_id==="d1") functionForDiv1();
   else if(div_id==="d2") functionForDiv2();
   ...
});
```

EDIT:

If you have everything inside that big div then you can do:

```
$("#displayPanel > div").click(function(){
...
```

Comment: $("#displayPanel div").click(function (){
alert($(this).attr("id"));
}

<div id="displayPanel" class="displayPanel">
   <div id="heading"> Display Panel </div>
<br/>
<div id="save" class="saveClass"></div>
<br/>
<div id="field1" class="my">
<label id="labelstr1">Untitled1</label>
<input id="inputstr1" type="text"/>
</div>
<div id="field2" class="my">
<label id="labelstr2">Untitled1</label>
<input id="inputstr2" type="text"/>
</div>

</div>
Its showing me the id for the first Two divs and not for the field1 /field2

Answer (score 8):

The loop seems unnecessary since the selector for div will apply to all divs.

```
$("div").click(function(){
  //this will apply to any div you click on the page
  //for example:
  $(this).css('color','red'); //change the color of the div clicked to red
});
```

**EDIT**: Since you mention in the edit that #field1 and #field2 are created on the fly, then you need to use [.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) to bind the click event as shown below:

```
$("#displayPanel div").live('click', function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: He doesn't necessarily want to apply to all divs.

Comment: Then he should use a class to specify which ones.

Comment: Or a custom attribute, as I suggest.

Answer (score 6):

You can, for example, loop through all div's like this:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    $(this).hide(); // this points to the current element
});
```

Comment: If any of my field1 /field2/field3 /field4 are clicked i want to take corresponding action separately likebelow
for(i=0;i<counter;i++){
  $("#displayPanel #field"+i+"").click(function (){});
}//for loop

Comment: Although using $.each() looks easier you get a performance hit compared to using a standard for loop.  It's negligible for smaller loops but as the count increases it can be many times slower.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have a for loop in jQuery, but by the look of your question, you might not need it. When you use

```
$('div').click(function(). { ... });
```

You can bind the function as an event handler for all divs with one command. You can also use [context](http://beardscratchers.com/journal/jquery-its-all-about-context), a [class name](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class#class) or [other attributes](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue) to filter the divs to which the event handler is applied.

If you wanted to perform a different action for each div, you would be best to have a unique ID on each div and then bind an event handler using

```
$('#divId').click(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the html is

```
<div class="module">
  <div id="header1">h</div>
  <div id="content1">c</div>
</div>
<div class="module">
  <div id="header2">h</div>
  <div id="content2">c</div>
</div>
<div class="module">
  <div id="header3">h</div>
  <div id="content3">c</div>
</div>
```

You can do loop this way with jquery:
For example, when you click header, the content is hidden.

```
$(".module").each(function(index){
   $("#header"+index).click(function(){
      $("content"+index).hide()
   });
});
```

You may want to have a look at jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) ) function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Do these `div`s have a common parent, attribute, or anything else? Matching by IDs of a certain form (i.e. `divXYZ` in your case) probably isn't the easiest/most obvious thing to do. The API documentation for [Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) has a complete list of the different ways you can select elements. Choose whichever is most appropiate for, and the JQuery becomes much simplified.

Here's an example for selecting divs with a **common parent**:

```
$("#parent > div").click(function() {
    // some code
});
```

And for selecting divs with a **common attribute** (if they don't have a common parent one solution could be giving them each a cusotm attribute):

```
$("div[fooAttribute]").click(function() {
    // some code
});
```