# How make a loop using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

I have a comma separated string. I split that string and assigned it to elements var.
How can I loop that elements var?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var element = $('#imageIds').val().split(","); 

    // how to loop this elements using jquery

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a standard loop like this:

```
var element = $('#imageIds').val().split(",");
var i;

for(i = 0; i < element.length; ++i) {
    // Do stuff with element[i]
}
```

Or you can wrap `element` as a jQuery object and use `.each` or `.map` or similar:

```
$($('#imageIds').val().split(",")).each(function(index, value) {
    // Do stuff with value
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments

Comment: @learner, On the left of each answer, there is a check.  Click it to mark that answer as *accepted*; i.e., that answer answered your question.  Please do this with some of your other questions, too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
var tempVar = element[i];
}
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

[Add jQuery click handler to mulitple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943987/how-can-i-make-a-for-loop-in-jquery)

This will help you..

Comment: I don't think this is related to what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function of jquery. It is used to iterate through element of an object.
[Here is nice tutorial.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/534-The-Beauty-Of-The-jQuery-Each-Method.htm)